# Operation not permitted

Tags: permissions, glibc

Got trouble with starting one app.

## Introduction

I have `Ubuntu-20.04-amd64` with core `5.x` on my VDS.
I have needed to install other core with some patch. But patch was available for `4.9.158` core version.
I built the core with patch and changed `grub` for new core loading.

Patch was needed for special possibilities in some programm.
After this, Im trying to start my app, but something went wrong.

## Trouble

```
/home/ejudge/solves/12345/26/in: error while loading shared libraries: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: cannot read file data: Operation not permitted
```

`libc.so.6` exists. I checked it.
[image]
I ran it as `root`.

## Updates:

Using KK's answer tried:
`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6`
`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`
`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so`
`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so`
`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6`

But it doesn't work.
P.S.: I clear variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` after each try and ofc `export` it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define and export `libc.so` library path.

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:<location of libc.so>
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Try to run application after that.

Comment: only `libc.so.6`?

Comment: I mean `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6` in my case